# Load JSON and display it on all the views in my Angular App

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have included code of index.html, app.js and json. I have created views needed with me. But I want to load the json and display it on all the views of my application. I am able to call the json on one page but not on the other views. Please provide me some pointers.

```
HTML Code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">


<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align:right">Visa Cares</h1>
        <h3 style="text-align: left">Total Body Transformation</h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="myController" >
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

            <li><a href="#/view1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/view2">Back</a></li>

        </ul>

        <button ng-click="clickButton()">List</button>



        <table border="0" cellpadding="3">

            <tr ng-repeat="x in modules">
                <td>{{x.filters}}</td>
                <td>{{ x.title}}</td>
                <td>{{x.feature}}</td>
                <td>{{x.order}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
<pre>
        <div ng-repeat="y in modules">
        {{y.buildings.building1.floors.floor1.rooms.room1 | prettyJSON}}
        </div>
</pre>
    </div>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div ng-view>

        Hello AJ
    </div>

    <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

    <div>
        <footer>
            <ul class = "nav nav-tabs">

                <li><a href="#/view1">Campus Buildings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view2">Conference Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view3">Hotteling Areas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view4">Huddle Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view5">Shuttle Schedule</a></li>
            </ul>

        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- In production use:
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
      -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
    <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
    <script src="view3/view3.js"></script>
    <script src="view4/view4.js"></script>
    <script src="view5/view5.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>




Controller Code:

'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var wfApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
    'myApp.view3',
    'myApp.view4',
    'myApp.view5',
  'myApp.version'
]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
    }]);


wfApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.clickButton = function() {
        $http.get('document.json').success(function(data) {

            $scope.modules = data.modules;
            $scope.modules = data.modules.buildings.building1;
        });
    }


}]);


I have a document.json which contains following data:

{"modules": [
          {
            "title": "Conference Rooms",
            "feature": "list",
            "filters": "Conference",
            "Order": 1,
            "icon": "conference.png"
          },
          {
            "title": "Hoteling Rooms",
            "feature": "list",
            "filters": "Hotel",
            "order": 2,
            "icon": "hoteling.png"
          },
          {
            "title": "Huddle Rooms",
            "feature": "list",
            "filters": "Huddle",
            "order": 3,
            "icon": "huddle.png"
          },
          {
            "title": "Shuttle Schedule",
            "feature": "shuttle_list",
            "order": 4,
            "csvInput": {
              "d1Pickup": [
                "8:00",
                "8:30",
                "9:00"
              ],
              "d4Pickup": [
                "7:50",
                "8:20",
                "8:50"
              ]
            },
            "icon": "shuttle.png"
          },
          {
            "feature": "map",
            "order": 0,
            "icon": "campus.png",
            "buildings": {
              "building1": {
                "order": 0,
                "id": "D1",
                "label": "D1 - 8910 Ridgeline Blvd",
                "floors": {
                  "floor1": {
                    "name": "1<sup>st</sup> Floor",
                    "order": 0,
                    "image": "floor1_map.png",
                    "rooms": {
                      "room1": {
                        "name": "Room 1",
                        "number": "D1-F1-1",
                        "occupancy": "12",
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Conference",
                        "coords": "100,100",
                        "hit_center": "80,80"
                      },
                      "room2": {
                        "name": "Room 2",
                        "number": "D1-F1-2",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Hotel",
                        "coords": "150,100",
                        "hit_center": "130,80"
                      },
                      "room3": {
                        "name": "Room 3",
                        "number": "D1-F1-3",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Huddle",
                        "coords": "200,150",
                        "hit_center": "180,130"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "floor2": {
                    "name": "2<sup>nd</sup> Floor",
                    "order": 1,
                    "image": "floor2_map.png",
                    "rooms": {
                      "room1": {
                        "name": "Room 1",
                        "number": "D1-F2-1",
                        "occupancy": "12",
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Conference",
                        "coords": "100,100",
                        "hit_center": "80,80"
                      },
                      "room2": {
                        "name": "Room 2",
                        "number": "D1-F2-2",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Hotel",
                        "coords": "150,100",
                        "hit_center": "130,80"
                      },
                      "room3": {
                        "name": "Room 3",
                        "number": "D1-F2-3",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Huddle",
                        "coords": "200,150",
                        "hit_center": "180,130"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "floor3": {
                    "name": "3<sup>rd</sup> Floor",
                    "order": 2,
                    "image": "floor3_map.png",
                    "rooms": {
                      "room 1": {
                        "name": "Room 1",
                        "number": "D1-F3-1",
                        "occupancy": "12",
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Conference",
                        "coords": "100,100",
                        "hit_center": "80,80"
                      },
                      "room2": {
                        "name": "Room 2",
                        "number": "D1-F3-2",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Hotel",
                        "coords": "150,100",
                        "hit_center": "130,80"
                      },
                      "room3": {
                        "name": "Room 3",
                        "number": "D1-F3-3",
                        "occupancy": 10,
                        "av": "Projector",
                        "phoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                        "type": "Huddle",
                        "coords": "200,150",
                        "hit_center": "180,130"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "settings": {
          "building": "D1",
          "floor": 4,
          "timeout": "120 (in seconds)",
          "cssOverride": "custom.css",
          "kiosk_coords": "200,200"
        }
      }
```

Comment: There's a lot of boilerplate code going on there. Try to reduce your question to the minimal problem. Posting a minimal example of what you want to do makes it easier to read and more probable that you get helpful answers.
Having said that, if I understand your question correctly I'd give you one main pointer: AngularJS services. They make it possible to reuse values across multiple controllers (and therefore views).

Comment: @LeoAntunes Thank you for your insights!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect use of a Service

// Adding injection of jsonService to controller

```
wfApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jsonService', function($scope, $http, jsonService) {

       // You can use jsonService.getJson() to get the file from anywhere the service is injected.
        jsonService.getJson().success(function(data) {
            $scope.modules = data.modules;
        });
      // Now your JSON is loaded (after promise resolves) and it can be used anywhere in the controller scope.
}]);
```

// Service to get the JSON file for use anywhere in the application

```
wfApp.service("jsonService", ["$http", function($http) {
  return {
    getJson: function() {
      return $http.get('document.json');
    }
}
}]);
```

The service can also be called in your $routeProvider using a resolve to load the JSON before the view is processed. This may be the ideal solution if you require the data immediately on page load for controller methods or data binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should try returning your "views" as partials via the controller. This way they can all use the same scope. Otherwise, you need to call the app/controller in each view in order to get access to the same json data within the scope.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Can we load the whole json without clicking event?

Comment: Sure, you can use angular $http to load the data into your controller. Check out the angular docs and using a "get" to load the json.

Comment: buzzsaw mentions the service. You can do this then call the json document.onload()

Comment: Thanks again. I knew about loading using $http but I wanted to know something like onLoad(). I will try that. Thanks for the help!!!